# How can I perform an action if a users input is the name of a file in a directory. Python

Tags: python, python-3.4

I am currently trying to make a program where the user can create sets of data, but I am having a difficult time figuring out how to handle the user picking the user picking a name out of a list of files to edit or view. 
Here is how I display the files they can choose from. How can I easily allow them to choose any one of the available files without hardcoding each individual one?

```
available_files = os.listdir('./DSC_Saves/')
print(available_files)
user_input = input('File Name: ')
```

What I would like to avoid doing is the following:

```
if user_input == available_files[0]:
    #do action
elif user_input == available_files[1]:
    #do action 2
elif user_input == available_files[2]:
    #do action 3
```

Comment: if input is in available_files then open it

Comment: @SirParselot Oh yeah. I completely forgot I could do that. I'm a novice at Python and this project had me a bit nervous, so I forgot some valuable information. Thanks.

Comment: user_input = int(input('Which file (1, 2, etc)?))-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, you can do this by using `in` on the list of available files as follows:

```
available_files = os.listdir('./DSC_Saves/')
print(available_files)

while True:
    user_input = input('File name: ')

    if user_input in available_files:
        break

print("You have selected '{}'".format(user_input))
```

Alternatively, to make it easier to type, you could present the user with a numeric menu to choose from as follows:

```
available_files = os.listdir('./DSC_Saves/')

for index, file_name in enumerate(available_files, start=1):
    print('{:2} {}'.format(index, file_name))

while True:
    try:
        user_input = int(input('Please select a file number: '))

        if 1 <= user_input <= len(available_files):
            selected_file = available_files[user_input-1]
            break
    except ValueError as e:
        pass

print("You have selected '{}'".format(selected_file))
```

Both solutions will continue prompting until a valid file name has been entered.

So for example you could see the following output:

```
 1 test1.txt
 2 test2.txt
Please select a file number: 3
Please select a file number: 2
You have selected 'test2.txt'
```

Comment: I like your solution, but I had found one as well and this seems fairly complicated to me as a novice. Though I will mess around with it a little bit.